# PHP, how I can "extract" all the substrings between square brackets?

Tags: php, regex

let's say I have a string like:

```
"there are some words, [other, could, be, here] then other words [and,more,here]."
```

or

```
"[one,two,three] something outside [than, more here, and more]."
```

I'd like to have an array of the brackets group, something like:

```
Array ( [0] => [other, could, be, here] [1] => [and,more,here] )
```

or anything I can use later, an object should be fine too.
Actually I've tried some regex, but with no luck, seems that I cannot take more than one group, or it has problems if the string starts with a match.

the regex already used for this are:

```
'/(\[\S+)\s(\S+\])/i'
'/\[([^]]+)\]/i'
'/\[(.*?)\]/i'
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `\[[^]]*\]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the square brackets and there must be a substring, you could do it like this:

[`\[[^[]+\]`](https://regex101.com/r/YJTx2u/2)

**Explanation**

- Match a square bracket `\[`
- Match no square bracket one or more times (*if there must be a substring, or else use `*` instead of `+` to match empty brackets [])* `[^[]+`
- Match a closing square bracket `\]`

For example:

```
$re = '~\[[^[]+\]~';
$str = "there are some words, [other, could, be, here] then other words [and,more,here].";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$result = [];

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $result[] = $match[0];
}

var_dump($result);
```

[Output php example](https://3v4l.org/E05c4)

If you want to match inside the square brackets, you could use

[`(?<=\[).*?(?=\])`](https://regex101.com/r/YJTx2u/1)

[Output php example](https://3v4l.org/ubRVp)

Answer (score 1):

expects "not nothing" to be between `[]`

`preg_match_all( '#\[([^\]]+)\]#', $string, $matches_array );`

`print_r( $matches_array );`

OR...

expects "something or possibly nothing" between `[]`

`preg_match_all( '#\[([^\]]*?)\]#', $string, $matches_array );`

also... place your backreferencing parentheses `()` around the countent you want to capture (do you really want to capture the brackets?)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use regex then ignore this answer but here is another way:

```
$str="there are some words, [other, could, be, here] then other words 
[and,more,here].";
$found=array();
$foundcount=0;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
    if($str[$i]=='['){
        $found[$foundcount]="";
        for($j=$i;$j<strlen($str);$j++,$i++){
            $found[$foundcount].=$str[$j];
            if($str[$j]==']'){
                $foundcount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
/\[[^\]]*\]/
```

Example:

```
$str = "there are some words, [other, could, be, here] then other words [and,more,here].";

preg_match_all('/\[[^\]]*\]/', $str, $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];
print_r($matches);
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => [other, could, be, here] [1] => [and,more,here] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
$str= "[one,two,three] something outside [than, more here, and more].";

preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: if you use wildcard without ? it makes it "hungry" -- which means it could go on matching to the LAST occurence of `]`